# Верстка слайдера контента, или почему это не работает ?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем доброго времени суток. Пропал мой верстальщик, а срочно нужно сверстать слайдер. Не могу понять - ЧЯДНТ. Вот собственно [проблема](http://jsfiddle.net/AHZBn/)
.items - должен будет ездить вправо влево, ну собственно это left: +-N
Не могу сделать так, чтобы элементы внутри .items были в одну строку.

Есть идеи ? :)

Comment: Ширину нельзя, элементы будут добавляться динамически :(

Comment: дак в чем проблема изменять ширину через javascript, в момент добавления элементов? не знаю, надо помотреть, как у других делается, может быть есть и другой способ

Comment: Дак это неверный путь к решению проблемы :) Я знаю что так можно, но я считаю что так делать не правильно, ибо для этого есть css + html :)

Comment: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html тут тоже указывается ширина. вообще, можно сделать это с помощью jcarousel. для анимации наверняка использовать jquery будешь? хотя, надо глянуть, есть ли там динамическое добавление элементов

Comment: позвольте с вами не согласиться. верстка сайта, да для этого есть html, css. а вот для таких вещей как раз и изобрели javascript. и ничего в этом дурного нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня специфичная верстка (так исторически сложилось), и именно поэтому я в примере указал в качестве элементов .item тэг <a>. Менять вёрстку не желательно( Если указывать ширину у .items - тогда действительно похоже на правду, но как быть, если элементов будет много много, и не хватит ширины ?) заведомо поставить очень большую ширину?) тоже вроде не best way :)

Comment: Двигать внутреннюю плашку - это да, задача javascript'a. А вот ширина блока - это по моему уже "лучше", и "правильнее" делать с помощью css. Зачем js'у при добавлении элемента внутрь блока - еще и менять его ширину ? Блок должен растянуться по горизонтали по содержимому. И это можно сделать, знал бы я прикольчики верстальщиков :)

Comment: да, есть способы растянуть его по содержимому, но насильно вытеснить за рамки подсилу только жестко заданной ширине. ибо без javascript такая фишка более чем бесполезна

Answer (score 1):

а ширину нельзя задавать? http://jsfiddle.net/AHZBn/1/
p.s. лучше float left

Comment: вообще не вижу тут проблем. решиения.
a) выпотрошить jcaousel и заставить её преобразовывать код твоей верстки, только зарание лучше посмотреть как она работает с динамически добавляемыми элментами
b) писать функцию addItem или что там уже есть, которая будет прибавлять ширину дива на ширину добавляемого элемента.

css'ом такую вещь вряд ли получится решить, потому что он заведомо так устроен, что не позволяет просто так выходить блоку за рамки элемента. разве, что есть какая-то хитрость для этого, в чем я сомневаюсь.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/1379/ читай совет мицгола